# Replacing the Side Indicator in Compare-Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am quite new to Powershell and my main sources of information have been reading books, watching Youtube videos and asking questions here, in hopes of finding help. So please excuse my lack of proper knowledge.

I have a script that asks for a path and gets the MD5 hash of the files and exports them in the desired path. I have made some changes to this particular CSV file and instead of it showing the Algorithm, Hash and Path, as Get-FileHash when exported to a CSV normally does, it shows things a little differently. Below is the code:

```
$p = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please type the full destination path of the Installer with a \ at the end'
$number = [regex]::matches($p,"\\").count
$csv = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the path where you want the CSV to be exported with the name and .csv at the end'
Get-ChildItem $p -Recurse | ForEach-Object{ Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} | Select-Object Hash,
    @{
        Name = "FileName";
        Expression = { [string]::Join("\", ($_.Path -split "\\" | Select-Object -Skip ($number))) }
    } | Export-Csv -Path $csv
```

This helps me change the columns in the CSV file and makes them look like this:

```
| Hash | FileName |
| ---- | -------- |
| 12345abcde | SampleFile.txt|
| abcde12345 | TestFolder1\File1.txt |
```

For instance if the path in question for the above code is C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ExampleFiles which contains **1** SampleFile.txt and **2** a TestFolder1 with a File1.txt in it, the columns in the exported CSV file will be displayed in the above shown manner.

I am writing a new script which I need that I can use to compare the hashes that I exported in the above script. I will have two CSV files of course. What I want to do here is to change the SideIndicator (<= and =>) to simply type a message which would be simpler to read. For instance if a file is present in the source and not in the destination, it would just type "Not found in destination files" instead of the SideIndicators. Also, for this I want it to display the File Name in the same manner that I showed above. Rather than the full path, I want it to display the path in the same manner that is shown in the table above.

Below is the code that I have worked on so far but it's not working for me.

```
$RHashPath = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the path of the source hash's CSV file"
$DHashPath = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the path of the destination hash's CSV file"
$number = [regex]::matches($RHashPath,"\\").count
$ReferenceHash = Import-Csv -Path $RHashPath
$DestinationHash = Import-Csv -Path $DHashPath
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $RHashPath -DifferenceObject $DHashPath -PassThru |
 ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" ) {
        $_.SideIndicator = 'Not found in destination files'
    }
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
            $_.SideIndicator = 'Not found in reference files'
        }
    } | Select-Object hash,
     @{
        Name = "FileName";
        Expression = { [string]::Join("\", ($_.Path -split "\\" | Select-Object -Skip ($number))) }
     }
) > C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Difference.csv
```

I can't get this to work. I want the Difference.csv to look like this:

```
|    FileName    |       Result       |
| ---------------| ------------------ |
| SampleFile.txt | Not found in source|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your script.

1. You're forwarding `$RHashPath` to `Compare-Object` instead of `$ReferenceHash`, same for `$DestinationHash`.
2. You've to define the properties `Compare-Object` should compare against via the `-Property` parameter, as stated under [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Compare-Object?view=powershell-7).
3. The `Foreach-Object` expression doesn't return any object back to the pipeline. Therefore `Select-Object` doesn't receive any objects to work with.

I hope I understand your complete question. Here is some code I came up with.

File1.csv:

```
Hash, FileName
abc, C:\file1.txt
def, C:\file2.txt
```

File2.csv:

```
Hash, FileName
abc, C:\file1.txt
ghi, C:\file3.txt
```

The code:

```
$RHashPath = Resolve-Path File1.csv
$DHashPath = Resolve-Path File2.csv
$ReferenceHash = Import-Csv -Path $RHashPath
$DestinationHash = Import-Csv -Path $DHashPath
$Result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ReferenceHash -DifferenceObject $DestinationHash -Property Hash, FileName  | ForEach-Object {

    # $_ is from type [pscustomobject] we can add a member via 'Add-Member'
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" ) {
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Result' -NotePropertyValue 'Not found in reference file'
    }

    # A property value appeared only in the reference object (<=) 
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Result' -NotePropertyValue 'Not found in destination file'
    }

    # Return the custom object to the pipeline
    $_
} | Select-Object @{N="FileName"; E={ Split-Path $_.FileName -Leaf}}, Result
```

The result:

```
> $Result

FileName  Result
--------  ------
file3.txt Not found in reference file
file2.txt Not found in destination file
```

If you want to convert the `$Result` to CSV:

```
$Result | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File C:\Result.csv
```

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes you got my question right. But this isn't returning anything for me and I want to export the results in CSV as well. Can you please give me some input on that?

Comment: @Aithorusa I've updated my answer with additional info about CSV export.

Comment: Sorry but there's just 2 more things. The results are both being displayed in the same column and are separated by `;`. And the FileName pattern is back to it only showing the name of the file. For instance if there's a folder and a file inside it, the FileName column should display it like this: `Folder1\Text123.txt`. I was able to do that with the previous code that I wrote at the very start but I can't figure out how to implement it here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only show the differences found as far as the `FileName` column concerns, but there are file hashes in the input csv files aswell and they can of course also differ.

I suggest you add these Hash values to the comparison too so you will get a morfe complete output:

```
$referenceFile   = 'D:\Test\File1.csv'
$destinationFile = 'D:\Test\File2.csv'
$ReferenceHash   = Import-Csv -Path $referenceFile
$DestinationHash = Import-Csv -Path $destinationFile

$result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ReferenceHash -DifferenceObject $DestinationHash -Property Hash,FileName |
    ForEach-Object {
        # capture the values before going into the switch
        $file = $_.FileName
        $hash = $_.Hash
        switch ($_.SideIndicator) {
            '=>' { [PsCustomObject] @{FileName = $file; Hash = $hash; Result = "Not found in reference file '$referenceFile'"  }; break }
            '<=' { [PsCustomObject] @{FileName = $file; Hash = $hash; Result = "Not found in destination file '$destinationFile'"} }
        }
    }

# output on screen
$result

# output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Difference.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
FileName                         Hash   Result                                           
--------                         ----   ------                                           
D:\SampleFile2.txt               123456 Not found in reference file 'D:\Test\File1.csv'  
D:\SomePath\SubFolder\A_File.txt acb987 Not found in reference file 'D:\Test\File1.csv'  
D:\SampleFile.txt                123456 Not found in destination file 'D:\Test\File2.csv'
D:\SomePath\SubFolder\A_File.txt acbdef Not found in destination file 'D:\Test\File2.csv'
```